# Ktor Android Retry Policy

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

How can I configure a custom retry policy for an Android Ktor Client?

My client instantiation code:

```
private var client: HttpClient = HttpClient(Android) {
    install(JsonFeature) {
        serializer = KotlinxSerializer()
    }
}
```

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: There is the `HttpRequestRetry` plugin that retries requests that failed due to network or server errors https://ktor.io/docs/eap/client-retry.html. Unfortunately, it's only available in Ktor 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Aleksei's comment, here is a solution:

```
private var client: HttpClient = HttpClient(Android) {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json()
        }
        //ktor.io/docs/eap/client-retry.html for more options
        install(HttpRequestRetry) {
            maxRetries = 25
            constantDelay(2000, 1000)
        }
    }
```

**Important: work's only for Ktor 2.0.0 or above.**